# How to parse command line arguments into an imported module via argparse

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I have a python script that uses `argparse` to parse command line arguments, below is an example from it.

```
#main.py

import argparse
from my_folder.myscript import foo

#...lines of code

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        "--test",
        action='store_true', 
        default=None
        )
       
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.test:
       foo()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

and `myscript.py` is

```
import pandas as pd
 
def foo():
    data = pd.read_excel('file/path/filename.xlsx', usecols = ['col1', 'col2'])
    print(data)   
    print(data['col1'].tolist())
```

If I use:

```
python3 main.py --test
```

I get the desired result. However I would like to parse the filepath of `.xlsx` or any other file in `myscript.py` via command line rather than in the `.py` file itself, i.e,

```
python3 main.py --test --infile /file/path/filename.xlsx
```

and ideally even giving further arguments like 'col1' to print second line. Can anyone suggest how to go about when trying to parse arguments into an imported module?

Comment: First you need to make your module actually accept the arguments in the first place. Make the path an argument of `foo`, then you can call it from main with `foo('file/path/filename.xlsx')` or whatever other path you need.

Comment: You can define the `foo` function like `def foo(filepath):`, and do something like `data = pd.read_excel(filepath)`.

Comment: Where's your problem?  Adding arguments to the parser, or passing the resulting `args` attributes to the `foo`?

Answer (score -1):

You need to describe what you expect from the command line via another `parser.add_argument`. There may be a number of them. If you do not code you than your script will never know what do you want to do.